# How can I get mouse wheel event in javascript firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, mousewheel

I'm building an website, and I need to get mousewheel event. In order to do that I've tried following methods:

```
//For Chrome
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', func);

// For Firefox
window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', func);
```

This one works only on chrome. ↑

```
mapDiv.onmousewheel = function(e){
    func(e);
}
```

This one too isn't working on firefox.
I've also tried solution suggested on [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/onmousewheel.shtml) webpage, but that also resulted in code only working on chrome.

So how to solve this issue, and also make solution compatible on as much as possible modern browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation, you'll see `mousewheel` is non-standard and suggest to use `wheel`event.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel

That refers to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel

Sometimes, the documentation solve the problem automagically.

You should use like this:

```
 // standard for all browsers
 window.addEventListener('wheel', func);
```

And here you are an implementation example for compatibility with legacy and modern browsers:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel#Listening_to_this_event_across_browser

Comment: I've tried this no success. Now it isn't working on both browsers.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what you are doing but it works for all browsers and IE9+ . To compatibility IE<9 use mousewheel

Comment: Thank you for helping me Marcos!